# Unknowledgable of single variabled integral

Tags: soft-question, definite-integrals, definition

Browsing [Stack-Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and other sites, I have noticed this come up quite a few times, an integral with only one letter or number! This would be a great example:

$$\int_{a}$$

What in the world does this mean? Thanks for any help whatsoever.

Comment: It's hard to tell without context. You should provide a specific example.

Comment: @AAron things like $\int_I$, $\int_D$, $\iint_R$, etc, you mean?

Comment: Right, yes exactly!

Comment: $I$, $D$, $R$ etc. are the integration domains. Like $\int_a^b f = \int_{[a,b]} f$.

Comment: @AAron These denote integrals over some object, like a line integral (along a curve), or a double integral over a region in the plane, or...

Comment: Ok, so primarily the region of cover by that integral?

Comment: Yes. Where region could be a measurable set, curve, surface, manifold etc.

Comment: @user251257 Do you mind if you showed me an example of something like this please and what it is equal to?

Comment: Notice that notation does vary. For example: If $S$ is measurable set of a measure space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$, then $\int_S f \mathrm d\mu$ is defined as $\int \mathbb 1_S f \mathrm d \mu$ for any measurable function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R$. Or, if $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb R^2$ is $C^1$ and $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$, then $\int_\gamma f(x) \cdot \mathrm d x = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t) \mathrm d t$.

Comment: You answered my question. Thank you very much

Comment: @user251257 Why not promote that comment to a full answer?

Comment: I would have accepted it. You can still go ahead.

Comment: Sometimes one also writes one integration extreme, because the other doesn't matter, e.g. in the following formula: 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int^t f(x)\, dx=f(t),$$ where the lower integration extreme does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a notation for the integration domain. The notation is used for measurable set, curve, surface, manifold, etc. Usually, if the exact content of the domain is not of interest or too complex to write out explicitly.

For example:

- If $S$ is measurable set of a measure space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$, then $\int_S f \mathrm d\mu$ is defined as $\int \mathbb 1_S f \mathrm d \mu$ for any measurable function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R$, where $\mathbb 1_S$ is the indicator of $S$.
- If $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb R^2$ is $C^1$ and $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$, then $\int_\gamma f(x) \cdot \mathrm d x = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t) \mathrm d t$.